Consider defining a bean of type service in your configuration
I have been learning Spring Boot for a week now yesterday I faced an error
`
Field db in com.example.test.tutorial.TutorialApplication required a bean of type 'com.example.test.tutorial.DB' that could not be found.
The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.test.tutorial.DB' in your configuration.`
TutorialApplication.java/Main class
package com.example.test.tutorial;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@ComponentScan("com.example.test.tutorial.AppConfig")
@SpringBootApplication

public class TutorialApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired(required = true)
     DB db ;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(TutorialApplication.class, args);
    }


    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        //System.out.println(db.getDb());
    }
}

Interface
package com.example.test.tutorial;  
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;  
 
public interface DB {      public String getDb(); } 

ProdDB
package com.example.test.tutorial;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

public class ProdDB implements DB{

    @Override
    public String getDb() {
        return "ProdDb";
    }


}

DevDB
package com.example.test.tutorial;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

public class DevDb implements DB{

    @Override
    public String getDb() {
        return "DevDb";
    }
}

Bean
package com.example.test.tutorial;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Configuration

public class AppConfig {


    @Bean
    public DB getDevBean()
    {
        return new DevDb();
    }
}

I have tried @SpringBootApplication and @ComponentScan but nothing seems to work , the same code is working in my friend's machine

Remove @ComponentScan. You're configuring it to scan the package com.example.test.tutorial.AppConfig that doesn't exist. If you don't specify it at all, the package that contains the class annotated with @SpringBootApplication will be scanned. TutorialApplication is in the com.example.test.tutorial package, the same as AppConfig so it will be picked up by component scanning and its beans will be defined.
Unrelated to your problem, but you don't need @Component on AppConfig. @Configuration is a specialization of @Component so you don't need both.

yes thank you I missed the point, I was also having some version difference
